# MainActivity.Kt and activity_main.xml is not found in android Studio

Tags: android

I am having a problem finding MainActivity and activity_main.xml in my project because they are missing. Can somebody help me how to fix this? I have provided a screenshot below.
[image]

Comment: switch the project view to android, in the top left corner where it says "packages"

Comment: May be your project not build successfully. Try to restarts the android studio and rebuild the project.

Comment: @beastlyCoder I have already done that but nothing happened. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Change your view from Packages to Android from project workspace...
You will see kt files under your package

Answer (score 0):

Change **Packages** file to **Project**. In the left top corner. It can help you to see all files.

[image]

Press twice Shift then you can see Searching dialog where you can search your **MainActivity**. After you can define where it is. If there is no **MainActivity** it might have been removed. Also for **activty_main**.

Comment: Search from ALL when you see dialog

Answer (score 0):

Restart android studio if it does't work then close android studio and go below path

```
C:\Users\Username\.android\
```

Then delete cache folder and now start Android Studio and Create new Project
You will be able to see that